# PDE for the probability of Brownian motion staying in an area (reference request)

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, heat-equation

I am looking for a (preferably some monograph) reference on the following fact:
$$
u ( t, x ) = \mathbb{P} \{ x + B_s \in A \ \text{for all} \ s \leq t \}
$$
satisfies the heat equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2} \Delta u
\quad \text{in} \quad \mathbb{R}_+ \times A
$$
and the following initial-boundary value conditions:
$$
u \ |_{t = 0} = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad u \ |_{\partial A} = 0.
$$

I'm struggling to find this particular fact among many facts of the same type. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem to follow (at least directly) from Feynman-Kac formula, nor does it follow from the other BM-PDE links I keep finding.

Additionally to the reference request, I'd like to know what's the most straightforward way to see this fact?

---

P.S. It seems to *formally* follow from Feynman-Kac, which says that
$$
u ( t, x ) = \mathbb{E} \left\{
f ( B_t ) \exp \left( -\int_0^t v(B_s) \, ds \right)
\right\}
$$
solves
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2} \Delta u - vu
$$
with $u \ |_{t=0} = f$. Letting $f=1$ and formally
$$
v ( x ) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & x \in A, \\
\infty, & x \not\in A
\end{cases}
$$
seems to give the result... Maybe it's possible to do it more rigorously by taking $v_n(x) = n$ on $x \not\in A$ and then letting $n \to \infty$.

Comment: What do you assume from $A$?

Comment: @m7e, I would actually like to know *what should I assume of it*... Being compact isn't necessary, but I have no idea how far the result stretches...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to show this is to check that if $\hat{u}$ is a bounded solution to your boundary value problem, then $\hat{u}(t-s,B_{s\wedge\tau}+x)$ is a martingale, where $\tau$ is the minimum of the exit time and $t$. This can be done e.g. using Itô calculus. But by Markov property of the Brownian motion, we have $\mathbb{P}(\tau= t|\sigma(B_{[0,s]})=u(t-s,B_{s\wedge\tau}+x)$, hence this is also a (Doob/Lévy) martingale. So, there difference is a bounded martingale, and we have by optional stopping theorem,
$$
0=\mathbb{E}(u(t-\tau,B_{\tau}+x)-\hat{u}(t-\tau,B_{\tau}+x))=u(t,x)-\hat{u}(t,x),
$$
where the expression in the first expectation is zero almost surely since $u$ and $\hat{u}$ have the same boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: I don't quite see how this proof works. First, showing that if $\hat{u}$ is a solution of heat equation $\implies \hat{u} ( t - s, B_{t \wedge \tau} + x )$ is a martingale is straightforward, I agree. But how do we show that $u(t-s, B_{s \wedge \tau} + x )$ with $u$ from my post is a martingale? Second, how do boundary conditions come into play here? And third, it seems that your proof requires $\tau$ to be bounded, but does it also work if $A$ is not compact?

Comment: @tsnao, I added some details, hope that helps! In the case $A$ is not compact, the solution to the parabolic problem is not unique, so you need to pick a bounded one (then the above argument shows that a bounded solution is unique).

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your argument for why $u(t-s, B_{s \wedge \tau} + x)$ is a martingale. I'm probably doing something stupid, but what you wrote doesn't seem enough...

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea ("PS") works fine, at least when $A$ has finite measure and is a moderately reasonable set (let's say open) and probably in general with more effort. It does seem to get a bit technical though. Here's a sketch:

We can also take $f=\chi_A$, $v_n=n\chi_{A^c}$, and then define
$$
u_n(x,t) = E\left( f(B_t)e^{-\int_0^t v(B_s)\, ds}\right) ,
$$
as you suggested. Then $0\le u_n\le 1$, $u_n$ decreases to $u$ and $u_n(t)=e^{-tH_n}f$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ with $H_n=-\Delta/2+v_n$. We have $(H_n-i)^{-1}\to (H_A-i)^{-1}\oplus 0$ strongly, with $H_A$ denoting minus one half times the Dirichlet Laplacian on $L^2(A)$.

This is not quite strong resolvent convergence since $0$ is not the resolvent of an operator, but it is similar in spirit and leads to similar conclusions. In particular, we will again obtain $e^{-tH_n}g\to e^{-tH_A} g$ for $g\in L^2(A)$ and since also $\chi_A u_n\to u$ in $L^2(A)$ by monotone or dominated convergence, this shows that $u=e^{-tH_A} 1$, as desired.

Comment: Nice argument. Does $(H_A - i)^{-1} \oplus 0$ means that it sends functions with support outside $A$ to zero? How do I formally see this convergence?

Comment: In one space dimension, we can solve the ODE $H_ny=iy$ explicitly (at least when $A, A^c$ are not too complicated) and build the integral kernel of the resolvent from these solutions. I'm not sure off the top of my head what a good general approach would be, but the fact that an infinite potential barrier imposes a Dirichlet boundary condition is "well known" (certainly to physicists).

Comment: Infinite potential barrier is exactly what I had in mind! Maybe I should look for a reference on how do people in PDE/spectral theory treat this subject... Is there a chance that it also works for unbounded domains?

Comment: Yes, I don't think any of the above assumptions are necessarily essential, I was just very lazy with the details. For example, $A=(0,\infty)\subseteq \mathbb R$ will certainly work.